# Calling COM in C# from VBScript with Array

Tags: c#, com, vbscript

Calling a COM function written in C# from VBScript is OK in first example with strings.

```
    public bool IsEqualTo(string firstString, string SecondString)
    {

    bool areEqual = String.Equals(firstString, SecondString, StringComparison.Ordinal);

    if (areEqual){

    return true;

    }

    else return false;

    }

VBScript: MsgBox oTestCom.IsEqualTo(one,one)
```

Unsure how to pass and manipulate arrays in second example. Is it best to use Array, ArrayList or Object?

```
public Array SortAscending (Array firstArray)

{
firstArray.Sort;

return firstArray;

}


VBScript: arrout = oTestCom.SortAscending("car","plane","boat")
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, use `object` as the array parameter type. In VBScript, construct the array using the `Array` function. Here is an example:

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MySampleComX
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {
        public void SortIntArray(ref object array)
        {
            if (array.GetType() != typeof(object[])) 
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument must be an array of integers");
            }
            array = ((object[]) array).OrderBy(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

VBScript code:

```vb
Set obj = CreateObject("MySampleComX.Class1")
arr = Array(3, 1, 2)
obj.SortIntArray arr
MsgBox Join(arr)  ' Outputs "1 2 3"
```

Comment: Output is "3 1 2", so not sure if call or function has worked.

Answer (score -1):

please try this, I try and can be work

C# code

```
   public object[] TestAray(ref object array)
   {
               
          if (array.GetType() != typeof(object[]))
          {
              throw new ArgumentException("Argument must be an array of integers");
          }
          var StrArray = ((object[])array).Cast<string>().ToArray();
          string[] res = StrArray;
                   
    
          for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
          {
              string tids;
              tids = Convert.ToString(res[i]);                  
           }        
    }
```

VBScript code

```
set obj=createObject("JustLib.TP_RateSchedules")
dim a
a=Array("5","10","15","20")
obj.TestAray(a)
```